# Is there a way to get non-personalized results with twitter Search API?and how?

Tags: api, search, twitter

I want to do some research using twitter's api. But it seems that when you use [twitter search api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) you'll get the personalized search result which is not I want.

So.. is there a way to get the non-personalized? If so, how?

Comment: Where does it say that it'll return personalized results?

Comment: @Bibhas https://blog.twitter.com/2011/engineering-behind-twitter%E2%80%99s-new-search-experience And I tried with two accounts, it returns different results

Comment: That's from 2011 and is about the site search. Plus, to get identical results using search API, you need to make queries at the same time. Twitter generated hundreds of thousands of tweets per second. Even if you are a fraction of second late, you'll get different result.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. thx :)